# $routeParam does not pass variable through url with $resource factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource, angularjs-factory, angularjs-ng-route

Code

```
var app= angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

app.factory('Greeter', ['$resource',function($resource){
  return $resource(
    'http://123.com/processor-url.php',{
      /*inputName:inputName,*/
      callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
    },{
      query: {method:'GET',isArray:true}
    });
}]);

app
.controller('appointmentController', ['$scope','routeParams', 'Greeter',
  function($scope,$routeParams,Greeter){
    /*alert("yes");*/
    alert($routeParams);
    var x = Greeter.query({
        myvar: $routeParams
    });
    $scope.output = x;
}]);

app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function($scope){
}])


/*Final Config After Loading Everything*/
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/appointments/:myvar', {templateUrl: 'appointments.html', controller: 'appointmentController'});
  $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'home.html', controller: 'homeController'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
}]);
```

Data (from http://123.com/processor-url.php when myvar=1066)

```
[
    {
        "myCodeId": "1066",
        "myCodeName": "session test",
        "myCodeOwner": "dvg",
        "myCodeBody": "",
        "myCodeTimesUsedCount": "0",
        "myCodeValueAsMins": "0",
        "myCodeCreateDate": "2014-07-30 11:04:58",
        "myCodeLastEditDate": "2014-07-30 11:05:43",
        "isSnippet": "0",
        "isDeleted": "0",
        "isMyFavorite": "0"
    }
]
```

I ran with this code + the data that suppose to be the result of myvar=1066.
There will be error of

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (.../urlTest/:29:24)
```

on the line where is

```
var x = Greeter.query({
```

I wonder where the mistake is? As I did inject Greeter inside the controller itself.

**==Update 1]===**

I updated the code by fixing all routeParam into routeParams.

Previous error is resolved. However, now the error becomes

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: routeParamsProvider <- routeParams
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/$injector/unpr?p0=routeParamsProvider%20%3C-%20routeParams
```

I maybe using the routeParams in a wrong way? Since what I wanted to do is that I assume routeParams will be the value of 1066 as thats what after the '/' symbol. Am I wrong in understanding its functionality?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone? No? Any more detail needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue i clearly see is the parameter mismatch for DI. This

```
 .controller('appointmentController', ['$scope', 'Greeter',
      function($scope,$routeParam,Greeter){
```

should be

```
 .controller('appointmentController', ['$scope','$routeParam', 'Greeter',
      function($scope,$routeParams,Greeter){
```

Also the service name is `$routeParams`

Comment: Now it returns error of Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeParamProvider <- $routeParam

Comment: Sorry the name is $`routeParams`

Comment: I updated some more explaination on what I intended to do, maybe that will provide more insight. Thank you!

Comment: Have you included the `angular-route.js` file in the main html page?

Comment: Yes, I did. and as wel as -resource.js

Comment: Also, I suspect that problem is somewhere with Greeter factory, because '$routeParams' is not a provider. isn't it?

Comment: Seems the route change got ignored as well because alert($routeParams.myvar); returns a undefined msg

Comment: Nvm, for some reason, I did not make it work, and now it worked... lol thanks!